Why is GridDB losing data after a node restart in a multi-node cluster?
I’m using GridDB to manage time-series data in a three-node cluster setup. Recently, I’ve encountered an issue where data seems to disappear after restarting a node. Here’s the exact scenario I observed:
Steps to Reproduce:

Start a GridDB cluster with three nodes (Node A, Node B, Node C).
Insert a set of time-series data into a container.

For example:
INSERT INTO temperature_readings (timestamp, sensor_id, temperature) VALUES 
('2024-12-19 10:00:00', 'sensor_1', 25.3), 
('2024-12-19 10:05:00', 'sensor_1', 25.5), 
('2024-12-19 10:10:00', 'sensor_2', 24.8);


Query the data to confirm successful insertion:

SELECT * FROM temperature_readings;

Expected Output:
timestamp            sensor_id   temperature  
-------------------  ----------  -----------  
2024-12-19 10:00:00  sensor_1    25.3  
2024-12-19 10:05:00  sensor_1    25.5  
2024-12-19 10:10:00  sensor_2    24.8  


Restart Node B in the cluster.
Query the data again from the same container.

After restarting Node B, the query output shows missing data. Some rows that were previously available are no longer returned.
Below are some relevant logs I extracted from the GridDB nodes:
INFO: Container 'temperature_readings' created successfully.  
INFO: Data written: 3 records.  
INFO: Cluster synchronization completed. All nodes are active.  

WARNING: Failed to synchronize data for container 'temperature_readings'.  
ERROR: Replica data not found for partition 4.  
INFO: Node rejoined the cluster, but data consistency may be compromised.  

